# 'Unexpected token export' when using gulp / webpackstream / vue

Tags: webpack, vue.js, gulp, es6-modules

I am trying to use vue's template compiler in my project via gulp and webpack-stream. The set up is something like this:

```
gulp.task('js', function () {

return gulp.src('./src/js/main.js')
    .pipe(webpackStream(
        module.exports = {
            output : {
                filename: 'bundle.js'
            },
            resolve : {
                alias: {
                    "vue$": "vue/dist/vue.esm.js",
                    // bind to modules;
                    modules: path.join(__dirname, "../node_modules")
                }
            }
        }
    ))
    .on('error', function handleError() {
        this.emit('end'); // Recover from errors
    })
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./js/'));
});
```

the error message is this:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token export
```

which is being caused by this:

```
export default Vue$3;
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you should remove `module.exports =` from your `webpackStream` parameter. It should be simple javascript literal object

```
 .pipe(webpackStream(
    module.exports = {
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
       output : { filename: 'bundle.js' },
  ...
```

Hope it helps